# I don't understand why almost the same code works faster

Tags: c++, sorting, assembly, optimization, time

I decided to brush up on my memory of sorting algorithms and write a small C++ library containing an implementation of every well-known algorithm. When it came to selection sort, I implemented it like this:

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
    void selection(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp) {
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)
            std::iter_swap(it, std::min_element(it, last, comp));
    }
```

For the sake of interest, I began to compare the speed of my algorithm with other implementations, which I found on the Internet and found out that the implementation below is more than twice as fast:

```
void selectionsort_1(int* l, int* r) {
    for (int* i = l; i < r; i++) {
        int minz = *i, *ind = i;
        for (int* j = i + 1; j < r; j++) {
            if (*j < minz) minz = *j, ind = j;
        }
        std::iter_swap(i, ind);
    }
}
```

I tried to find the reason for this on the internet, but without success. Later, I noticed that storing the value of the minimum element and a pointer to it does not make much sense and changed the code a bit:

```
void selectionsort_2(int* l, int* r) {
    for (int* i = l; i < r; i++) {
        int* min = i;
        for (int* j = i + 1; j < r; j++) {
            if (*j < *min) min = j;
        }
        std::iter_swap(i, min);
    }
}
```

To my surprise, the modified algorithm ran in the same amount of time as my implementation, i.e. worse. I decided to see what assembly code the compiler generates for each of the two previous code options and did not notice much difference.

[selectionsort_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4mb.png)

[selectionsort_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DtCA.png)

Perhaps I came to the wrong conclusion, but is it really a difference in one mov command that can slow down or speed up the code twice?

P.S. Below I attached an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQqu7.png) of test results on an array of random integer numbers with a dimension of 100,000 elements. Project configuration: Release.

Comment: Remember to enable your compilers optimizer for even greater speedups.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre]  that we can compile ourselves (including how you measure the time taken)

Comment: Where is code doing measurements? Are you aware that performance measurement is hard? Is is full of traps, since is AS IF rule can transform code is such way that you do not measure thing you wish to measure.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the answer! However, the optimizer was enabled from the start

Comment: One possible reason can be that derefencing the `min` pointer can cause a cache miss if the pointed to element is far enough away from what `j` points to at the moment. Though given enough iterations the cost of the pointer dereferencing could also become a factor

Comment: You say it's release but those codes do an awful lot of local variable accessing on the stack for an optimized build.

Comment: What is the exact command line used to compile the code?  And which compiler, on what platform?

Comment: @UnholySheep
Example: https://pastebin.com/LfAqEDkC

Comment: Can't reproduce [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/ZnAqwU9vTK-4E14nMk9jySnZLeE) [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/RUb1sT31x5c5jtYx-zjjpXFQr4M).

Comment: @Eljay I use Microsoft Visual C++ compiler

Comment: @MarekR I use Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. Language standard is C++20

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results on my local Windows machine either, `selectionsort_2` is slower, but `sort::selection` is almost 6 times faster than `selectionsort_1` when I run in release mode (running on the latest update of MSVC2022)

Comment: What is the exact command line used to compile the code? And which version of Microsoft Visual C++ compiler?  On Windows 32-bit, or 64-bit?

Comment: @UnholySheep Before this I was using MSVC2019. Now installed the latest version of MSVC2022, and everything works as you wrote, thanks! The reason for the difference in the execution time of the functions seems to be that you indicated earlier

Comment: @Eljay

Command line: /permissive- /ifcOutput "Release\" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Ot /Fp"Release\test.pch" /diagnostics:column 

Version: now MSVC2022

Windows 32-bit

Comment: @Eljay
After replacing the compiler with MSVC2022, the algorithm with iterators really began to work much faster, however, selection _1 and selection _2 still have different running times. I also tried the assembly under Windows 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [ask] help page. For one thing, I think the title here could use improvement.

Comment: Your screenshots of disassembly are from debug builds.  They're keeping local pointer variables in stack memory, so `*j` is `mov eax, [ebp - 2Ch]` / `mov ecx, [eax]`, for example.  I don't know what all the MSVC options mean, but `/O2`, or `/Ox` enable optimization.  The version using STL functions being slowest is what you'd expect in a non-optimized build, since the functions wouldn't inline.  But your question doesn't say anything about compilers or versions or options; [edit] to update with info from comments.

Comment: See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987).  And to some degree [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391) but that's mostly about less branchy code, other than the fact that It's Complicated.